# how to define a cursor value with string?

Tags: android, string, cursor

i have this string 
"android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@44defce0"
how can i make a cursor value with that string?

```
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    input = auto.getText().toString();//this class use implements TextWatcher

    KamusDbAdapter x = new KamusDbAdapter(getApplicationContext());
    x.open();
    Cursor cur = x.getCall(input, selection);
    x.close();//getCall() to get cursor from sqlite result

    String[] displayFields = new String[] {"word", "meaning"};
    //word & meaning are fields inside the table
    int[] displayViews = new int[] { android.R.id.text1,android.R.id.text2 };

    auto.setAdapter(new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, cur,displayFields, displayViews));

}
```

onitem click invoke

```
auto.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            main = auto.getText().toString();
            result.setText(main);
            auto.setText("");
        }
    });
```

Comment: It looks like you are adding the cursor to the ListView. Post your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not quite sure what your code has to do with your question, but you can use `MatrixCursor` to create cursors in code. For example:

```
  MatrixCursor cursor = new MatrixCursor(new String[] {"column1"});
  cursor.addRow(new String[] {"android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@44defce0"});
```

This will give you a cursor object with a single column named "column1", with a single row containing the string you mention. This cursor can then be passed to an adapter expecting a cursor, if you wish.